# Alter procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to alter  existing procedure in MYSQL, so as per I know we don't have that option in MYSQL.  Every time we need to drop procedure and recreate,  so is there any way  we can  alter procedure  without dropping the existing one.

Answer (score 3):

According to MySQL Docs, you can alter a procedure using [`ALTER PROCEDURE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-procedure.html), unless you need to change the procedure's parameters or it body.

> This statement can be used to change the characteristics of a stored procedure. More than one change may be specified in an `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement. However, you **cannot change the** parameters or **body** **of a stored procedure** using this statement; to make such changes, you **must drop and re-create the procedure** using `DROP PROCEDURE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: ya thanks for information, according to this no other way to alter procedure.